# Would the usage of a TestPropertySource with a SpringBootTest annotated test result in the creation of a new Spring Context?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Would using a @TestPropertySource, that creates a new Bean in the application, result in the creation of a new Context or would it reuse an already created context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Test manages the context within a context cache and uses a uniquely identifiable key for each context (think of a simple Java `Map`).

The parameters that are used to create this key [are the following](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching):

> - locations (from @ContextConfiguration)
> - classes (from @ContextConfiguration)
> - contextInitializerClasses (from @ContextConfiguration)
> - contextCustomizers (from ContextCustomizerFactory) – this includes    @DynamicPropertySource methods as well as various features
>   from    Spring Boot’s testing support such as @MockBean and @SpyBean.
> - contextLoader (from @ContextConfiguration)
> - parent (from @ContextHierarchy)
> - activeProfiles (from @ActiveProfiles)
> - propertySourceLocations (from @TestPropertySource)
> - propertySourceProperties (from @TestPropertySource)
> - resourceBasePath (from @WebAppConfiguration)

So yes, if you use `@TestPropertySource` with different configurations for multiple tests, there will be multiple contexts created for you. If all your test have the same `@TestPropertySource` annotation, then they can share the context, e.g.:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ContextOneIT {

  @Test
  public void testMe() {
    System.out.println("Works");
  }
}
```

can share the same context with

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application.properties")
public class ContextTwoIT {

  @Test
  public void testMe() {
    System.out.println("Works");
  }

}
```

If you are curious and want to understand what Spring Test is doing, you can enable the following log level to get context related logs:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.cache=DEBUG
```